# Can code-only answers be high quality?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, code-only-answers

I don't like asking about audits, because it sounds like complaining, but I'm not sure about this:

I've been review-banned once, and I haven't failed any audits since then (a few weeks ago), but I just failed [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5001309) and now I'm banned for a week.

It's essentially a code-only answer, and from what I've seen here (not much, so take this lightly), those generally aren't well accepted.

Comment: You reviewed the *First Posts* queue and a post with 13 upvotes from a 3k user did not make you suspicious?

Comment: @juergend The user card is anonymized when actually reviewing the audit; it's only revealed after the fact

Comment: What action did you take?  Did you downvote, flag, comment, or what?

Comment: I've seen plenty of excellent code-only answers.

Comment: That's a reason I tend to always open the question/answer in another tab before reaching a verdict on a review. That said, for code-only answer, unless the description of what the code does is within the code comments, you should minimally comment that it needs a description of what the code does.

Comment: FWIW, I hate code-only answers. Typically, if someone needs help then an explanation of the code is going to go a long way in helping people in the future.

Comment: @Servy I downvoted; I didn't give much thought to it at the time, though I did read through it. I just figured it was one of those new users who knows how to solve the problem, but needs instruction on how to answer questions properly: I was going to leave a comment asking for explanation of the code, but, of course, it was an audit, so I didn't get the chance.

Comment: If it is any consolation, I would have downvoted that answer.

Comment: @codeMagic Sometimes the best explanation is in-line comments, though.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I agree they can be very helpful but I still like to see *some* explanation outside of the code. I don't see very many times when an answer wouldn't be improved by at least a minimal explanation leading into the code.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Is the code self-documenting, concise, and complete?  If so, then the answer is yes.

Is the code obscure, hard to understand, or incomplete?  If so, then the answer is no.

In the answer you linked, the code was concise, complete, and easy to read.  It also included a sample output in a comment within the code sample.  Seems fine to me.

Comment: +1 If it has comments, clear variable and function names, then yes

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia Good code is code that doesn't need comments.

Comment: @bjb568 no, that's code. Good code is also well documented. The code explains *how*, the **comments explain the why**.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia Good code doesn't *need* comments, but of course comments are helpful in explaining why. If you're explaining how however, either your code is crap or the language is crap.

Comment: That's what I meant, sorry but I'm not English native so I didn't say that clearly :/

Comment: @bjb568isceilingkat Both good code, and good answers, *do need comments **when you're posting it to SO***. You shouldn't assume that every reader will be familiar to the Programming Language and/or APIs being used, and instead, even if your code seems very intuitive to you, you should assume that ***the reader***, meaning ***any reader***, is *not* an expert in the languages or APIs being used, and will ***not*** understand ***why*** the *code-only answer **works***, which is far more important than *simply knowing **that** it works*.

Comment: @AlmightyR Generally, yes, comments on SO are pretty much mandatory if you want OP and googlers (who are only there *because they are ignorant*) to understand your answer. But it's not always completely necessary, for example if your code is very simple, but just not something that's easy to think of as a beginner.