# New answer-deletion option: code-only answer

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts

My question is somewhat related to [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258673/can-code-only-answers-be-high-quality), in that, it seems to me that many answers flagged as low-quality are code-only answers. While Will's answer to the previous question indicates that *some* code-only answers are acceptable, I feel that they could usually be improved with just a little extra effort from the answerer.

I propose that we introduce a new "Code-only Answer" deletion reason with the following canned comment:

> While this code-only answer may solve the problem at hand, more explanation is necessary to help future users of the site understand how to apply this solution to their situation.

Do you agree that this is a step in the right direction?

Comment: Sorry to see you get so many downvotes. I think this is a good question, and essentially getting all 'no' answers doesn't make it a bad one to ask. After all, I came onto meta thinking to ask the same thing but am satisfied by the reasons given here why it won't work.

Comment: @Numeron that's just how meta works. It's cool.

Comment: @num this is a feature request. You should downvote it if you don't want it implemented.

Comment: why not blocking those answers from posting like questions? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can find on Stack Overflow a Japanese user who follows one of the same tags that I follow. This user understands English (and the code in the questions) well enough to know exactly what is going wrong, and often expresses their solution as a code-only answer.

These code-only answers are usually the best answers the question receives, even if occasionally they may not be recognized as such. Even when the majority is not brilliant enough to give this user's answers the attention they deserve, I always do, because I know it to be rewarding.

If you chase this user away from Stack Overflow, I will make it my mission to chase you away from Stack Overflow.

Nah, I'm kidding. But I would be sorry if you bother this user. Some ignoramus might contribute to make them feel unwelcome by using the deletion reason that you suggest, and this site needs more users like them, not fewer.

Comment: Accepted because this speaks to the real heart of the issue: that the best answerers are not always the best writers in English.

Comment: I can understand language barriers, but if a user can read and understand the question is expecting a some small **attempt at explanation** really asking too much?

Comment: Just saying that broken English can be edited into shape, usually with little effort, so this isn't really a good reason to support code only answers.

Comment: Would be nice to have a canned response for code-only answers that end up in the low-quality answer review queue that wouldn't end up deleted. I usually leave a comment like _"While this may answer the question, it doesn't provide any context to explain how or why. Consider adding a sentence or two to explain your answer."_ and click **Looks OK**

Comment: If the answer is not understandable (because it has no explanation) is it the best answer? If it's technically great but the OP (and future visitors) doesn't understand it or can't spot what's been changed then for me it's of limited use when compared to an answer with a full and complete explanation a long with the code.

Answer (score 41):

A code-only answer **is still an answer**.

It may be a bad quality answer, but that does not warrant deletion!

If you must, downvote such posts instead, as a code dump is not necessarily helpful. Remember that the Low Quality review queue is not just there to delete posts. You can also edit posts to improve them, or comment to leave feedback.

Comment: Regarding down-votes, I seem to have a problem with the review queue UI. The option to down-vote is either not there or is not easy to find within the queue itself. I'll need to work harder to learn the system.

Comment: @AustinMullins: That's not what that queue is for. It is for deleting absolute crap and/or salvaging what can be salvaged. Of course, you are free to do more.

Comment: @Austin: sorry, I forgot the vote buttons are not available in the LQ queue. You can follow the direct post link. The goal is more to say 'Agreed, it is absolute crap' or 'Nah, this is good enough, let it be'.

Comment: I actually do support the OP's request, in some cases, especially [things like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773844/sorting-list-in-linkedlist) (which prompted me to come here - around this time of night I start to see a ton of Code-only questions + Code-only answers). I think these types of answers *do* warrant deletion on two grounds: 1) They hurt the OP more than help, which is the opposite of what we want, and 2) They encourage more answers of the same type just by being here as an example. However, I understand and agree with the counterpoints as well.

Comment: I don't agree and think we should re-evaluate this. While this may be true for many code-only answers, some of them really do need an explanation. When reviewing low quality posts I often stumble upon code-only answers that would profit from an explanation (while others wouldn't). These answers were flagged as **low quality** for a reason.

Comment: @Exa: at which point **downvoting** is the right action. The flag you are thinking off is called 'very low quality' and should only be used for posts that are unreadable gibberish. See [How should the "very low quality" flag be used?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/291598); if code-only answers were flagged as such then those flags were incorrectly used.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think OP's question relates to low quality questions in general, that are displayed during reviews as *This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.*. When I review low quality posts most of them are not unsalvageable or unreadable. This is the kind of question I was referring to. I agree, of course, that downvoting is one way of showing that a code-only answer needs more explanation, but a comment would help the author of the answer even more, which is the reason why an auto-comment during low quality reviews would be helpful in my opinion.

Comment: @Exa: commenting is something completely different from outright *deletion* however, which is the end goal of flagging. Flagging is appropriate when there's something wrong with the content that the community can't handle on its own, but for code-only answers, the community can handle that on their own just fine. If you want to leave a comment, then just leave a comment, we don't need flags for those.

Answer (score 11):

Late answer, but important topic - I was about to post on this. I believe that we need some "Looks OK Mostly" options...pre-typed suggestions for improvement that don't warrant closing.

My own stock answer is...

> Please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.

Definitely not ground for closing (usually), but something reviewers need to be encouraged to notice.

Comment: Using [AutoReviewComments](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se), we kind of do. Although obviously there's precedent for promoting those into the SE interface....

Answer (score 5):

The opinions on the code-only answers went like this (see also: [Flag 'Try This: {code}' Answers as "Very Low Quality"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality/256360#comment257404_256360)):

- many code-like answers are not very useful to anyone except the OP (sometimes, even them)

  - yet, they are still routinely upvoted and accepted. Which practitioners use as their defense. That's because they have an audience: users who are only interested in a ready-made solution for the specific task / something to copy-paste mindlessly

    - still, even if they're useful *for them*, **they are not useful for SO goals** which are to disseminate *knowledge*, a task that code without explanation often does a mediocre job at
- *some* code-only answers nevertheless manage to be perfectly fine, conveying all the knowledge needed

So, **we cannot delete code-only answers just for being code-only answers.** and thus **cannot add the proposed reason** (accepting it with reservations like "unless real good" won't work: followers always tend to be overzealous about whatever the teachings dictate).

Corollary:

- **To get rid of bad code-only answers, we must not delete them because they are code-only but because they are, well, *bad*.** This may mean:

  - incomplete (unclear without explanation, do not specify limitations, side-effects etc.)
  - bad-quality code, bugs

As it was noted, these reasons may not necessarily warrant outright deletion but rather downvotes. There are, however, obstacles on this course of action:

- [no vote buttons in VLQ UI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140405/why-is-voting-removed-from-new-review-system)
- [the fine payed by a downvoter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue?s=4%7C0.6041)

Discussing these topics are out of scope of the current question, but they do hurt the validity of the arguments of those who propose downvotes as the primary course of action.

Answer (score 0):

That "many answers flagged as low-quality are code-only answers" does not mean that "many code-only answers are flagged as low-quality", which in turn doesn't imply that they should be *deleted*.

Or would you really delete [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3504894/183406)? Even though it is accepted with 64 upvotes?

Comment: It says "many", not "all". Statistics anyone?

Comment: Not all code-only answers are bad. But there are those that are flagged as low-quality and your example of course wouldn't fit this category. The question is about handling **low quality code-only** answers.

Answer (score -4):

The problem with the issue as it stands in 2017 is that there still is wide-spread difference in opinion in the community.  As someone who occasionally goes through the low-quality queue, I see that some leave comments, some likely downvote, and some answers are left untouched.  I have no idea how many recommend deletion and how many Looks Ok we get because I am not privy to that information.

Another trend I notice is that low rep people get the comments far, far more than the 4 and 5 digit rep users get.  There most certainly seems to be a correlation between rep and being called out.  After all, it somehow seems wrong to delete an answer by a 10K user.

To answer the question, I would say an answer should be flagged, but not deleted for code-only answer.  Deletion is too harsh for many of these technically correct answers.  More to the point though, there should be an official policy on what to do with these type.  So if Looks Ok were the decided upon answer, those who recommend deletion are subject to ban just like any other review queue poor decision.

Comment: If the code answers the question it is an answer.  You can down vote it but we do not have a flag for just low quality answers.

Comment: `I am not privy to that information`  Yes you are.  All actions of all reviews are public.  Anyone can see them, even if you're not logged into the site.

Comment: As a reviewer in the LQP queue, you either delete the post because its merits deletion or you don't.  Some people may choose to downvote, or comment, and those actions are often warranted on these types of posts, but that's outside the scope of the queue.  From the queue's perspective, you don't delete these posts, because they don't merit deletion.  `So if Looks Ok were the decided upon answer, those who recommend deletion are subject to ban just like any other review queue poor decision.` That is indeed the case.  Voting to delete an answer that doesn't merit deletion is a wrong review.

Comment: Instead of thinking as those comments as "calling out", try thinking of a down-vote as calling out the answer as bad, and the comments as "hand-holding through the process of salvaging the answer".  10k users don't need to have the possible solutions listed for them, they already know the quality standards, so just downvote whatever isn't high quality,