# Failed Audit: Not sure why

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Failed an audit in the Low Quality Posts category by clicking "Looks OK" with what seemed to be a reasonable attempt to answer the question by providing code. Now, this was not the answer of the century, and if someone provides code with no context I'd usually downvote or comment on it. But it wasn't so bad that it needed to be immediately purged in my opinion. Questions like this one ([New answer-deletion option: code-only answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262695/new-answer-deletion-option-code-only-answer)) seem to be on my side here.

I'd rather not click "I understand" when I don't. The audit is here for those that can see it (I cannot, going off of memory): https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5333222

Here is a screenshot of the answer in question

[image]

Comment: Anyone (with 10K) up to adding a picture?

Comment: @Deduplicator It was marked as spam but [here is the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24385463/revisions)

Comment: @codeMagic: Now if you say that's properly marked as spam, that's good for me. But I cannot see that revision history: I don't have 10K.

Comment: @Deduplicator sorry, I thought you would be able to see the history if I linked to it. I'm not sure what the code is doing but there is a link at the bottom which references a site to interview questions which doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question.

Comment: @Deduplicator there you go. That should help.

Comment: Aaaand nearly the exact same thing happened again not even a week later. Not going to bother making another discussion about it, just going to take a long break from reviewing until the system is in order.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That's a bit of a tricky case. The original answer was flagged as spam, because the user in question posted a series of answers like this, all with irrelevant links to their site at the end. They had spammed this site before, and this was another clear attempt by them to spam, which is why the spam flag was accepted and the answer removed. That made it an audit case.

However, you couldn't have known that context from the above, so I've cleared the spam flag on it so it won't be used as an audit case in the future.

Comment: You guys should have a field like "not usable as audit" instead of having to un-flag it. Dunno, sounds awkward to me to un-flag it for that reason.

Comment: @CamiloMartin - [That would be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790), wouldn't it?

Comment: Oh my! So many upvotes and still unimplemented. I'd figure it'd be very easy to implement given that the codebase to this site is likely top-notch (at least server-side, because the HTML manages to have table layouts and divitis *at the same time*).

Comment: @CamiloMartin: I don't think that the powers that be want us to learn from audits, but rather filter people out that are not perfectly in line with the algorithm to generate the audits, and then drive people away from doing reviews. Works fine for me.

Comment: @PlasmaHH That can't be, the idea of audits makes sense in theory. I mean, it's the only stopgap from people auto-auditing.

Comment: @CamiloMartin: It is just that with all the bad audits, plus the overly unforgiving ban system, it drives the people that do reviews  because they believe in making things better away. It is quite a big collateral damage to get those people away (which anyways doesn't work at a lot of places because some audits are just too easy to spot; oh and don't make the mistake in skipping them).

Comment: @PlasmaHH what happens if you skip the audit? I never tried that.

Comment: @CamiloMartin: It looks like the "should you be banned" algorithm takes into acconut not only the number of failed, but the number of successful audits. So if you tend to skip them, you dont have a record of successes, and failures count more (disclaimer: pure speculation based on various observations)

Comment: @PlasmaHH As someone who was previously banned from meta SO in a semi-permanent fashion (the ban lasted a few years, but my regular SO account was intact), I think banning users does not motivate them to contribute more :P But maybe there are just so many bad users that the benefits of ban-happy administration make up for its losses. Maybe we were just unlucky winners.