# Low quality posts and code only answers

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts, code-only-answers

In low quality posts review queues there are many answers which just contain little code snippets without explanation.

If the code solves the question there should be an auto-comment possibility that explanation is desired. If the code does not solve the question there should be an auto-comment possibility for "why code only answers are bad" and the answer may be deleted.

***Edit:*** This topic specifically suggests an auto comment for code-only answers. The topic of the low quality posts queue in general with a lot of clarification was extensivley talked about here: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Do you agree?

Comment: Just downvote answers that are not useful. If you want to leave a comment to explain that code without an explanation is not helpful, go ahead, but such posts do *not* need to be deleted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes however those posts are often flagged as low quality and they should be handled appropriately.

Comment: @gnat Your duplicate suggestion is a great addition to the question however I asked for some really specific feature in order to improve the handling of low quality posts by commenting instead of deleting and this is why I think the topic should be considered.

Comment: @Blackbam: Moderators generaly decline Low Quality flags on code-only posts.

Comment: And what about code-only answers that explain the approach with inline code comments? Most languages have inline comments, right?

Comment: @MSeifert The moderator still has the option to decide. The comment should be formulated in a way such that it only is applied to disatisfactory code only answers.

Comment: @MSeifert I think in-code comments are OK. After all, what we want is that answerers explain what their code does in plain English - it doesn't matter how that explanation is presented as long as it's readable.

Comment: related: [New answer-deletion option: code-only answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262695/new-answer-deletion-option-code-only-answer)

Answer (score 75):

Sometimes you really do not need to explain anything and the code itself is the answer.  That said I prefer if an answer actually explains why the code block is the answer.  To that I have a [auto comment](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) in the form of

> While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

source:

> `While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.`

It would be cool if that was presented as a popup when a user submits a code only answer.  I think a popup would be better than a comment as the mechanics to remove that comment when the user does add an explanation would be pretty complex to get right.

Comment: Yes I like this idea a lot.

Comment: I have something similar: `Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.`

Comment: Sometimes this one is more appropriate: `This question is looking for an *explanation*, not simply for working code.  Your answer provides no insight for the questioner, and may be deleted.  Please [edit] to explain what causes the observed symptoms.`

Comment: I also like the idea of a popup! Sometimes even a very nicely worded auto-comment has caused the code-only answerer to insult me for "attacking" them, which is just unpleasant.

Comment: "solve the question" => "solve the problem", or better yet, "be a solution"

Comment: @CodyGray Great suggestion.  I like that and I've updated my auto comment.

Answer (score 9):

There is no need to add another option to support this case, especially given the unclear distinction between whether or not the code snippet "solves the question".

To reiterate the guidelines laid out in the [linked post](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/2747593): answers that consist of nothing but a code snippet **should not** be deleted.  (But they should be edited, either by the author or by another user.)  The auto comments being referred to here are only an option when selecting "Recommend Deletion", so it doesn't makes sense to add a comment that applies to answers that shouldn't be deleted.

If you want to have the ability to insert such an auto comment (without recommending deletion), I recommend installing the [Auto Review Comments GreaseMonkey script](//stackapps.com/q/2116/39235), and updating the config with an auto comment such as this one:

> `While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)`

Comment: Maybe add the option comment but not delete to SO natively? Maybe add recommend deletion with comment for useless/obviously wrong code obly answers?

Comment: They handle link-only answers also in recommend deletion.

Comment: @Blackbam 1. I don't think auto-comment-but-don't-delete is worth the effort to build into SO, especially since user scripts for this already exist, with more functionality than SO could hope to include. 2. Wrong answers, even obviously so, are not eligible for deletion, and should instead be downvoted. 3. You are correct that link-only answers should be deleted, but this is because they introduce an unnecessary dependency on an external site, rendering them useless if the site goes down. Code-only answers have no such dependency.

Answer (score 7):

I agree that something has to be done in order to face this problem.

The Low Quality Post review queue has one of the best designs among all the queues. By clicking on <kbd>Recommend deletion</kbd> most scenarios that might occur have the correct "bucket" to select:

- In case of "Not An Answer" scenario, the "Thanks", "commentary", "Me too", "Another question" and "Should be an edit" options are provided
- Also in case of "Link only answer" we have the corresponding option
- The "No comment needed" option covers the scenario in which the answer is *really* low quality in formatting and contents, the spam and the one in which someone else has already selected the option you think is correct and you don't want to append the same comment again

---

**What is missing?** Well, of course **code only answers**!

- *Can we recommend deletion?* 
  No, we can't. Even if low quality it might be useful for someone looking for a code solution.
- *Does it look ok?* 
  No, it doesn't! An answer containing code can **always** be explained. The logic it contains, the functions you used, the reason why it works to solve OP's issue.
- *Can we edit?* 
  Theoretically yes. But first of all, as far as I know, editing "too much" in the contents of an answer is considered rude, as it would be really easy to *conflict with the author's intent*. Secondarily (but not too much), the main value of an answer is IMHO the explanation, and it represents the main effort of an answer. It wouldn't be fair.
- *Can we comment?* 
  Actually we can, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> that well known comment mentioned in the other answers. But there's a drawback: the author of the answer could ping us asking to review the edited answer... but what if we don't know anything about that topic? They could also argue that their answer is ok as it is, or even revenge downvote us. 
  And what if they correct the answer without pinging us? Who will ever come back to check that answer? 
  Last, but not least: **commenting doesn't count as a completed review**.
- *Can we skip?* 
  Yes. And that's what we're going to do for all those posts. And those posts represent at least 60% of the LQP queue.

Not only systematically skipping all those posts is frustrating, but it is definitely inefficient. I see only three alternative options:

1. Those posts should not be sent to LQP, as they will probably be skipped. So the corresponding flags should be declined.
2. Commenting those posts should count as a completed review.
3. A specific "bucket" for this kind of answers has to be created. The meaning of the bucket might be discussed. Some ideas:

   - Three users reviewing an answer as code only could send it to a ***suspended reputation*** status. The answer is not deleted, but it wouldn't produce reputation until the post is corrected.
   - The answer is marked as incomplete. Its author will have a permanent notification until the post is either corrected or deleted. Reaching a maximum threshold of *incomplete answers* could lead to a temporary suspension from answers.

Comment: "Can we skip? Yes. And that's what we're going to do for all those posts." This just kicks the problem a few minutes down the road for the next reviewer who comes along. Since code-only answers should not be deleted, and since reviewers should not put words into the OP's mouth, the proper action would be to press "Looks OK" (even though it doesn't look OK, it's just not *deletable*) while also adding a comment and perhaps downvoting. The UI is not optimal. Maybe something along the lines of "Should not be deleted" would be a more precise button name, but that's a mouthful

Comment: @CertainPerformance I agree with you. I have to say that though _the UI is not optimal_ I consider it the best designed queue. That's why I would like "my favourite queue" to be perfect. The problem resides in the fact that all those alternative actions you suggest don't count as a review action.