# How to handle answers that are just code?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, code-only-answers

In the moderation options, there is no specific flag for "this is just some code" when someone posts an answer with only code and no explanation as to how to what that code does, or how it resolves the authors problems.

How should these be moderated?  I would think a specific moderation flag type should be added for "please explain the code you are recommending".

Comment: Why isn't downvoting sufficient?

Comment: See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345720/4342498

Comment: auto-comment.  Didn't know about that one, thanks.

Comment: They are awesome for moderation purposes.

Comment: @yannis It is. But should come with a comment explaining it.

Comment: If you are feeling charitable, I guess @MarounMaroun.

Comment: @yannis I do downvote also but feel like I should point out to the author exactly WHY it is being downvoted, which the link NathanOliver posted covered perfectly.   I also have to laugh at how my own post here was edited to remove "Thank You", which I do all the time when I edit other people's posts but yet still added it to this one.   *shrug*

Comment: @Patrick If you have the time and energy to comment, by all means, do. Just don't forget to downvote first.

Comment: @yannis Will do, just as this post currently stands at -4!  Not sure why, seemed like a reasonable question I just couldn't find the meta discussion on it until I saw the link above.  Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry about the downvotes, [voting is different on meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would think a specific moderation flag type should be added for "please explain the code you are recommending".

I'm afraid that such a flag would not be useful and will never be added.

Flags are, essentially, a convenient way for you to request that a moderator step in to handle a problem occurring on the site. With the aid of the larger community (*i.e.*, privileged users), we step in to handle spam and nonsense answers, off-topic questions, and all sorts of content that violates our Be Nice policy. Moderators will also step in to handle plagiarized content appearing in answers (but you currently need a custom flag for that, as there is no standard one available).

There's no flag for answers that are just code because there is no workable way for a moderator to deal with that scenario. The only thing we could *possibly* do would be to delete the answer, and although I agree that such answers are of terribly low quality, I just cannot justify their outright deletion. I doubt that you can, either.

What these answers *really* need is to be edited into shape, adding some context and explanation around the code. Unfortunately, moderators are not equipped to do that. We don't have moderators who are experts in all topics/technologies that fall within Stack Overflow's scope, and couldn't possibly hope to. Even if we worked out some type of escalation system, it just wouldn't scale.

One possible solution is to have the community edit these answers into shape. But nothing special needs to be done in order for that to happen. The people who are most capable of doing so are already browsing these Q&A, so all they need to do is get inspired and click the "edit" link. (The last thing we need is another "review" queue for this, so again, a flag would not make sense.)

Unfortunately, people don't often get so inspired. It's hard to blame them. Editing other people's pathetic code dumps into good answers is a lot of drudgery, probably more time-consuming than just writing your *own* quality answer, and you don't get much (if any) credit for doing so.

If you want to edit and improve these answers, then more power to you. If you don't, then I understand.

Just downvote them instead, on the basis that *"this answer is not useful"*. If you like, you can also leave a comment. Be very careful to avoid implicating yourself as the downvoter in your comment; focus only on the problems with the post as you see them and a possible solution.

Comment: Excellent explanation of the scenario.  It makes me fully agree that my original idea of a specific flag is off the mark.  Downvoting and leaving a comment as to WHY is logically the best way to handle this.  

I don't feel comfortable trying to explain why a code sample might resolve the issue, even if it's an area I'm experienced in.  That's up to the person who left the comment.