# Does this answer meets the criteria?

Tags: discussion

I was reviewing some answers when and then this answer came along: [VBA Name a Sheet with ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49976486/vba-name-a-sheet-with-combobox/49976590#answer-49976590)

To quote the answer:

> use
>
> ```
> Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
>     Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
>     ActiveSheet.Name = ComboBox1.Value
>     Me.Hide 
> End Sub
> ```

I didn't think this answer deserved to be deleted but rather improved with some more information, as how this answer would fix OP's problem.

In my opinion this answer only suggested something without any information whatsover given, except a piece of code.

---

So I added a comment under his question

> Explain how this helps to solve the problem and what the OP did do wrong.

He replied with:

> OP has already everything he needs. and even more (two unnecessary code lines and one unnecessary variable)

So I replied:

> Yes I know, but I think you should add a little explaination to your awnser. Like the accepted anwser did in his snippet using comment lines.

When he replied with:

> the explanation you require is right in the accepted answer

Now I am a little confused. Was my judgement wrong? Mainly because his reputation is more than mine is, so he likely has much more experience than I have.

Was my judgement right? Or was the given answer correct and no need for any addition?

Comment: I am not experienced with VBA but in some situation a code only answer is pretty fine and self-explained. I usually write answers like `you need to use this code ...` and I cannot add more information as the code is pretty well clear. The only thing I can do is to describe the code which can be trivial and obvious by simply reading it.

Comment: The judgment you left when leaving a comment? That's fine. And you may even down-vote if you feel the answer is poor and not useful in its current state. That being said, the poster is free to disregard your comments if they want.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Alright, I agree with that. I felt in the particulair awnser that he should have noted why he left out a piece of code from the original questions code block. And changed it.

Comment: @yivi Yes, thank God we can disagree with each other :). I didn't feel it was bad enough to downvote it though.

Comment: If you are asking if it's worth _flagging_ that answer, then then answer is **no**. The answer might be of higher or lower quality, but is still an answer.

Comment: My question is actualy. Should that answer supply more information as 'why does this answer fix OP's problem'. There was no need to flag it in my opinion.

Comment: I usually leave a comment saying "Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer always requires some explanation on how the problem was solved". I totally agree that code-only answers might be helpful for op if it just changes a view small things, but for everyone else it's not that helpful. Ever tried to find the one different line in 50 lines of code?

Comment: Small side note. You could have been a bit nicer when requestion the explenation. Currently i read it like: _"Explain your answer!"_ Another option would be: _"Can you explain your answer?"_

Comment: @AndréKool Uff, I hope that guy didn't felt it like that. As I didn't intend it like that :o

Comment: @BDL The quote you supplied `"Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer always requires some explanation on how the problem was solved"` actualy anwser my question. But also agree with @yivi, its still an anwser. Even it being a poor one. Thansk everyone, I think I got it clear now.

Comment: To clarify: I leave this comment (and might change it to something nicer since I agree with @AndréKool) and choose "Looks OK". Code only answers are [according to this post ok](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345719/low-quality-posts-and-code-only-answers). They could just be better. (Actually this question could maybe be closed as a dupe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really a decision you have to make.

Not everyone here is an expert in VBA, and not everyone can make an empirical statement as to whether or not an answer is "right" or "wrong" based on just a glance without context.  The big thing here is that you genuinely feel like the answer is lacking, so you have a better idea of feeling like the answer is useful or not useful.

Even after the comment chain it doesn't feel like the answerer feels that their answer needs refinement, but you clearly disagree.  You should take that into account here.

In that circumstance, I *beg* that you vote accordingly.  Upvote it if you think it's useful and correct.  Downvote it if you don't.  You don't need to involve us on this.