# What action to take for answers that don't answer the question?

Tags: discussion

I recently got the privilege to recommend action for low-quality posts and in my first queue, I came across a post that was written by a user with more than 5k reputation but had absolutely nothing to do the posted question?

[This is the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566843/how-to-extract-text-from-html-page/53077533#53077533) I am referring.

Editing is out of the question, I don't want to skip and recommending deletion seems too harsh. What should be the course of action in these cases?

---

**EDIT**

The reason why I couldn't come to recommend deletion was due to the reasons I had to select from. My options are

- No comment needed
- This is commentary on another post, not an answer
- This is a “thank you” comment
- This is an “I’m having this problem, too” comment
- This is a different question posted as an answer
- This is a link-only answer (and not spam)

None of these accurately describe the post.

Comment: So you don’t want to edit but also don’t want to delete? There aren’t a lot of options in between. Why shouldn’t this answer be deleted?

Comment: It's a VLQ  answer, at least the _code only_ without explanation justifies flagging as such.

Comment: @Xufox, I have added an explanation in the edit section of the post. Please take a look

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, should low quality posts be recommended for deletion? Or should they only be downvoted?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Code only answers are the be flagged as VLQ? Are you sure about that? When you encounter them in the queue you are supposed *not* to delete, after all.

Comment: Downvote. Comment if you want. Move on. That an answer is altogether wrong is not a reason for deletion with current rules.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ [Code only is not very low quality.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345719/low-quality-posts-and-code-only-answers)

Comment: down voting is your only option.

Comment: What strikes me more is that the answer contains an URL to some Italien (newspaper?) site. Since I don't speak Italien I can't say if this is just some random url or spam.

Comment: @BDL they posted an almost identical answer, using a different url, I guess to prevent they are seen as spamming a particular site. No spam in my book.

Comment: There are 2 separate issues, if I understand it correctly: 1. That it's code-only (leave a comment there, possibly downvote, I tend to skip these or press _Looks OK_ if I'm pretty sure it answers the question). 2. That it doesn't address the question. If an answer doesn't address the question, but doesn't fit in the pre-defined comment categories, the appropriate choice is _No comment needed_, preferably after leaving a comment (Yes, seems contradictory, I know)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth, Thats what I have done here. Left a comment and selected *No comment needed*. Thanks