# Auto comment on code only answers from Low Quality review

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts

Today I was reviewing some Low Quality Posts, and I noticed that I pressed "Skip" in about 80% of the cases. While there inherently is nothing wrong with skipping I sat for a moment and wondered what caused me to skip all these answers.

The reason being that they mostly were code-only, or code with some added words like: "Try this:"

After a while I came across [this review item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/25791869), an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51662934/how-can-i-convert-date-in-a-column-to-a-epoch-timestamp-in-bash/61066983#61066983) that simply stated:

> ```
> sed 's/20[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/echo `date --date="&" +"%s"`/e' inputfile > outputfile
> ```

I then noticed a comment on this answer, originating from the Late Answer review:

> While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61066983/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/25791864)

A comment I felt I could have left on 99% of the review items I just skipped.

Now as to the validity of code only answers, there has been discussion:

- [Flag 'Try This: {code}' Answers as "Very Low Quality"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality)
- [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

With the conclusion being that it being code only doesn't make it delete-worthy.

Now as I don't consider a code-only answer to be an OK answer, nor  to be something I, or most likely anyone else for that matter, can edit into a real answer it just leaves the Skip button as the only escape. Using the Skip button does, well exactly nothing. And thus offers no solution in shortening the queue.

As I would like to see these code-only answers improved into real answers I could go about adding comments manually, which some people do. Which is really great!, but not something all reviewers do, or are able to do.

**So I propose** that we add that excellent comment I quoted above, as something we can add to a code-only answer with the simple click of a button.

I see several options where we could implement this, either under the "Looks OK" or under the "Skip" button, just in a similar fashion as the automated comments are included under the "Recommend Deletion" button.

Comment: I would really like to see such a comment. But keep in mind [that code-only answer are "Looks OK"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue) unless they are not related to the answer.This post is also related: [Low quality posts and code only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345719/low-quality-posts-and-code-only-answers)

Comment: @BDL, I knew there was this apple's picture somewere, just couldn't find it. Thanks, I added it in.

Comment: I wonder if that will confuse reviewers when you can say something looks okay, but still should request improvements.

Comment: @Tom I think it does. Lots of code-only answers are incorrectly deleted from the LQP queue.

Answer (score 4):

When <s>ninjas</s> mods are online, the Low Quality Posts and Late Answers queue are flooded with those code-only answers that... "Look OK". For the last couple of days, I have been adding the comment you saw in these posts, with the help of the [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/q/2116) userscript.

I see that many authors are willing to edit their post to add explanation because of... reputation and upvotes! I get replies like "edited, hope it will now get more upvotes".

I am in favour of adding such comments like this one, but looks like this is not the biggest problem.

1. Answerers should know, before they answer, that code-only answers attract downvotes and are generally not welcome.
2. Reviewers should be made aware that code-only answers shouldn't be deleted. Perhaps a 7th option should be added in the Recommend Deletion dialog: "This is a code-only answer". The review would be "Looks OK".
3. Don't dispute flags on LQP "Looks OK" consensus if the answer is code-only and warn the flagger if they are going to flag such an answer.