# Failing a review audit due to trying to add a comment

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I'm not sure how many of you can see this, but the review item [is this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/26269150). The answer was a code block, preceded by the text "I guess..." I tried to add a comment to the answer, requesting them to give more detail about how the answer solved the problem, and how "I guess..." probably wasn't the comment to provide.

I failed as the answer was "High quality".

My understanding of this site is that we don't simply post code, but give an explanation, in writing, of how it answers the question posed. The "I guess..." doesn't meet this expectation. In this area, there isn't clear guidance about providing [good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). However, this sentence on the page, "We don't expect every answer to be perfect, but answers with correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar are easier to read," suggests that some explanatory text should be provided.

There has been at least one [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment) post in the meta mentioning that they failed an audit for the same reason - trying to add a comment.

Comment: Perhaps a better quote from that article is "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."

Comment: Basically, a review queue is not the place to add comments (except those automatically added by the system, of course). There is a link to the right of the post you can use to open the post in a new tab/window if you'd like to add comments.

Comment: @HereticMonkey If we're not supposed to add comments in review, then there shouldn't be a link to add a comment.

Comment: An Haskell answer ... that are guaranteed audits ... We don't review Haskell, Haskell reviews us ...

Comment: @JohnMontgomery The whole point of an audit is to catch you doing something you're not supposed to be doing, so if they removed the UI for doing the thing you're not supposed to be doing, there'd be nothing to audit... But I don't disagree. Not much I can do about it though.

Comment: The other post mentioned is really the canonical of this complaint. There's nothing us normal meta folk can do about it, and I don't think there's much moderators can do about it (except on a case-by-case basis). So, we all have to wait to see if Stack Overflow, Inc., decides to honor that feature request.

Comment: @HereticMonkey That's just pointless entrapment then. If you're not supposed to comment in the review queue (and this is the first time I've seen someone say that) then it shouldn't give you the ability to do so in the first place.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Yep. Preaching to the choir. Let's hope one of these feature requests actually happens... Or even better, one of those, *and* one of the requests for manual audit selection rather than the craptastic automated selection they have now...

Comment: @HereticMonkey If I remember correctly the guideline says to comment if a post should be improved. I think it also says to downvote. Alternatively one can edit, but in this case one would have to add an explanation that was never there in the first place, so that's a bit bordering on authors intent. Any of these would in this case have resulted in a failed audit.

Comment: @Scratte Not sure what guideline you're referring to. All I'm going by are the various meta posts complaining about the fact that commenting made the reviewers fail an audit. Based on those, I don't comment in review queues. Perhaps my logic is faulty, but I haven't failed an audit in a long time.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Ahh. I comment on every post I flag. And on code only posts. I've failed audits, but also not in a long time :) So I don't think that's the measure. Some are just good at noticing when it's an audit. I think [Low quality posts and code only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345719/low-quality-posts-and-code-only-answers) is the end of the line on duplicates of how to handle code-only answers.

Comment: @rene I tremble at the thought of disagreeing with you! However, I managed to close a Haskell post today, during [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/26270076). I was astounded, to say the least. It was reopened very quickly, though.

Comment: How do items go into the Audit review? Who makes this decision. Perhaps stop putting essentially code-only answers into the audit review queue *if these are supposed to be okay*. My reading of the guidance for answers is that some sort of explanation of the code is expected. The one I failed for commenting had no explanation.

Comment: @Michelle Items automatically go into the queue based on votes, whether they're deleted, etc. Nobody is choosing to put those specific items into the queue, the system just messes up sometimes.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Thank you.