# Ambiguous audit reviews for answers?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I recently was reviewing posts and was met with an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5383660) that needed review. The answer presented to me was a code only answer. My understanding of code only answers is that while they can be helpful at times, they are still frowned upon and we should *always* encourage those who answer questions to not only provide code, but also provide an explanation of why their code *is* the correct answer along with any other information they feel would be helpful to the person who posted the question no matter how simple the code is.

As you can see in the screenshot, the answer I was given to review was a code only answer, so I simply clicked the 'add comment' button so that I can explain that a description as to why this is correct would be helpful, no matter how simple the code is. However, it was then that I found out it was an audit that I failed simply because the answer was categorized as high quality, even though in my opinion it is not since it doesn't provide any explanation, reference, or clarification.

IMHO, answers that have been upvoted, yet do not adhere to what many of us consider to be high quality, introduces ambiguity when thrown in the audit review process. They promote an inadequate assessment as to what really is a high quality answer and what we as a community should be teaching our members to focus on when identifying high and low quality answers.

Cheers.

[image: Review]

Comment: If you hit a code-only answer, take _extra_ time to review it, and only do so if you know the material. Usually it's not delete-worthy. Just because the author did not include an explanation does not mean we should blap it.

Comment: If you want the post to not be an audit then downvote it.  Congrats, you've prevented that post from ever being an audit again and you can move on with your day.

Comment: @gunr2171, I agree that they are usually not delete worthy, and in this case I agreed that the answer solved the issue, but was simply going to add a comment asking the poster to explain their answer so the person who asked the question and anyone else that happens upon it, can understand it well. In situations where code only answers are given, I've encountered many situations where people still ask the poster to explain the answer, regardless of their expertise with said code/language. Cheers.

Comment: @gunr2171, thank you for the link, I'll read up on that. Cheers.

Comment: @gunr2171, Thank you so much for that link, it summed up my concerns much better than I did in my own post.  And you are correct, my post can be considered a duplicate of the post you linked to, close vote submitted. Cheers.

Comment: More recent dupe:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258673/1228