# The code-only answer filter seems to be broken

Tags: bug, answers

I've been coming across answers like this recently: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25531385/1344955

They only have one single code block with no surrounding text. I thought this wasn't allowed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [*no such filter* for answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258673/can-code-only-answers-be-high-quality), only for *questions*.

That said, feel free to leave a comment on such answers, asking the author to add an explanation as to why the answer solves the problem. If the code contains comments that do so, that's fine, but the answer you linked to lacks any and all explanation.

Also remember the tooltip on the downvote button: *This answer is not useful*. If you feel a code-only answer is not useful, you could use that button to express that.

Comment: I wish there was a filter for that, though. Thanks for the explanation.